# IP ping internally but not externally

Tags: debian, ip, ping

Yesterday, my DEBIAN server went down and I have to reboot.
After that, several web sites did not go up and I found that 2 IP above 3 do not ping. The main IP still works and attached web sites work.
LAMP is OK.

When I externally (e.g. from a CMD window on my PC) ping IP, it does NOT respond (timeout)
When I internally (e.g. from a SSH window) ping, it DOES respond.

Here the ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 38:60:77:59:ab:d5  
      inet adr:94.23.45.172  Bcast:94.23.45.255  Masque:255.255.255.0
      adr inet6: fe80::3a60:77ff:fe59:abd5/64 Scope:Lien
      adr inet6: 2001:41d0:2:2eac::/64 Scope:Global
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:30087 errors:0 dropped:8 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:42372 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
      RX bytes:3059473 (2.9 MiB)  TX bytes:42177957 (40.2 MiB)
      Interruption:20 Mémoire:fe500000-fe520000 

eth0:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 38:60:77:59:ab:d5  
      inet adr:91.121.34.20  Bcast:91.121.34.255  Masque:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      Interruption:20 Mémoire:fe500000-fe520000 

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 38:60:77:59:ab:d5  
      inet adr:149.202.31.242  Bcast:149.202.31.255  Masque:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      Interruption:20 Mémoire:fe500000-fe520000 

lo        Link encap:Boucle locale  
      inet adr:127.0.0.1  Masque:255.0.0.0
      adr inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Hôte
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:3952 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3952 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 lg file transmission:0 
      RX bytes:591562 (577.6 KiB)  TX bytes:591562 (577.6 KiB)
```

I do not see anything.
Can you help?

[EDIT]

When I trace the route under a distant CMD window:

The IP that works:

```
C:\Users\Bruno>tracert 94.23.45.172

Détermination de l'itinéraire vers ns3453432.ip-94-23-45.eu [94.23.45.172]
avec un maximum de 30 sauts :

1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  OpenWrt.lan [192.168.29.1]
2     1 ms     2 ms     2 ms  172.31.131.1
3    37 ms    37 ms    37 ms  10.0.131.1
4    48 ms     *        *     ovh.franceix.net [37.49.236.144]
5    48 ms    47 ms    48 ms  gsw-g1-a9.fr.eu [213.186.32.210]
6    52 ms    52 ms    52 ms  rbx-g2-a9.fr.eu [91.121.131.213]
7    51 ms    51 ms    51 ms  vss-1b-6k.fr.eu [91.121.131.74]
8    52 ms    52 ms    52 ms  ns3453432.ip-94-23-45.eu [94.23.45.172]

Itinéraire déterminé.
```

The IP that DOES NOT work:

```
C:\Users\Bruno>tracert 149.202.31.242

Détermination de l'itinéraire vers ip242.ip-149-202-31.eu [149.202.31.242]
avec un maximum de 30 sauts :

1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  OpenWrt.lan [192.168.29.1]
2     2 ms     1 ms     1 ms  172.31.131.1
3    37 ms    36 ms    37 ms  10.0.131.1
4    47 ms     *        *     ovh.franceix.net [37.49.236.144]
5    49 ms    49 ms    48 ms  gsw-g1-a9.fr.eu [213.186.32.210]
6    52 ms    51 ms    52 ms  rbx-g2-a9.fr.eu [91.121.131.213]
7    53 ms    52 ms    53 ms  vss-1b-6k.fr.eu [91.121.131.74]
8     *        *        *     Délai d'attente de la demande dépassé.
9     *        *        *     Délai d'attente de la demande dépassé.
10     *        *        *     Délai d'attente de la demande dépassé.
11     *        *        *     Délai d'attente de la demande dépassé.
12     *        *        *     Délai d'attente de la demande dépassé.
13     *        *        *     Délai d'attente de la demande dépassé.
14     *        *     ^C
```

It shows that the destination servers are not the same:

- ns3453432.ip-94-23-45.eu => OK, this is my server
- ip242.ip-149-202-31.eu => NOK, I don't know what is this server? Maybe it's normal? the IP server of my provider?

[EDIT]

Result of "ip address":

```
: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN 
link/ether 56:3d:d8:48:8f:18 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN 
link/ether b6:7a:a9:a6:7f:e3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
link/ether 38:60:77:59:ab:d5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 94.23.45.172/24 brd 94.23.45.255 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 91.121.34.20/24 brd 91.121.34.255 scope global eth0:0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 149.202.31.242/24 brd 149.202.31.255 scope global eth0:1
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:41d0:2:2eac::/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::3a60:77ff:fe59:abd5/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN 
link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
6: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN 
link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
7: ip6tnl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1452 qdisc noop state DOWN 
link/tunnel6 :: brd ::
```

I don't know if it helps?

[EDIT]

iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport     dports ssh
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state   RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:2222
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imap2
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3s
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:1337
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:webmin

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state     RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:2222
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ntp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imap2
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3s
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:iscsi-target state NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

And route :

```
Table de routage IP du noyau
Destination     Passerelle      Genmask         Indic Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         vss-gw-6k.fr.eu 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
91.121.34.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
94.23.45.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
149.202.31.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: The second hostname (the one you wrote NOK at) seems correct to me as the domain is meant for the `149.202.31.0/24` subnet and the subdomain indicates that the last octet is 242 which is your IP.
Have you checked the firewall? Try disabling it temporarily to see if that helps. Also, please post your routing table on the server.

Comment: Sorry, I'am a noob. I dont know exactly how to suspend the firewall. In my cas, it is iptables. I have tried "iptables -F INPUT". But then the server became unreachable. I had to reboot.

Comment: I have edit my question above and add the result of "ip address". I don't know if it helps?

Comment: Try posting the output of `route` and `iptables - L`

Comment: One strange think about this server ip242.ip-149-202-31.eu : If I PING it externally, there is NO response. But if I ping it from my server, it responds. I don't what is this server? I discover it when I trace my IP. OVH did not tell about it. I guess it's a IP server?

Comment: Hi Frederik. Can you take a look to my route and iptales that I have added this week-end? Even, if you don't find anything anormal, please tell me also. THANK.

Comment: Don't mind that domain - it is just something OVH uses internally to map IP's to a domain name (so-called PTR's). I'll look at the rest of your info later today